# How to filter multiple tags with django-taggit in admin view?

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm reading through the [documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#filtering) for any example, alas without success. Can anybody point me to an example about filtering for e.g. "green" and "blue" in django admin view?